# 301 to new url and ssl

Tags: 301-redirect

A client wants to create a 301 to his new site that also happens to require ssl. Here's an example of what he wants:

```
http://www.abc.com  to https://www.efg.com
https://www.abc.com to https://www.efg.com
http://www.abc.com/product?id=1 to https://www.eft.com/product?id=1
https://www.abc.com/product?id=1 to https://www.eft.com/product?id=1
```

I'm reading up on using .htaccess file but it's not sinking in. Wondering if someone could present an example that would accomplish the above and explain it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.abc.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.efg.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and you'll need to repeat for any additional subdomains or edit above regex to match all subdomains by doing `abc.com$` (no carat at beginning which means "begins with")

On `RewriteRule`, the `^(.*)$` means everything after domain/host. And with this section `https://www.efg.com/$1`, the `$1` tells the first sub regex match element (the first thing in bracket) to be appeneded after `www.efg.com/`.

You can also do it via httpd.conf file.

```
<VirtualHost *>
  ServerName www.abc.com
  Redirect 301 / https://www.efg.com/
</VirtualHost>
```